# Implicit function theorem and Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Prove that equation $$x\ln w+w\ln y=0$$ sits in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$, variable $w$ as function of $x$ and $y:$ $w=g(x,y)$.

Prove that $g$ is of class $C^\infty$.

Write second Taylor polynomial of $g$ in $(1,1).$

Comment: Your title suggests you already know you have to use the implicit function theorem, so where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how show that g is of class $C^\infty.$ I can't write g as mathematical formula, can I?

Comment: That follows from the fact that around $(1,1,1)$ the function $(x,y,w)\mapsto x\ln w+w\ln y$ is $C^\infty$, this follows inductively by differentiating once, twice, etc...

Comment: Could you tell more about this? I don't know how to connect fact that $xlnw+wlny$ is differentiable with that g is differentiable.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) section of the implicit function theorem's page on wikipedia. Now forget about your problem and conclude as a corollary, by induction, that if $f$ is $C^\infty$, then so is $g$.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that if ${\partial g(z) \over \partial z} = h(z)$, and $h$ is of class $C^r$, then $g$ is of class $C^{r+1}$.

To avoid a notational morass, write $f(w,z) = z_1 \ln w + w \ln z_2$, and note that $f$ is smooth. We have
$f(1,(1,1)) = 0$. The implicit function gives some differentiable $g$ defined on a neighbourhood of $(1,1)$ such that $g((1,1)) = 1$ and we have
${\partial g(z) \over \partial z} = - {1 \over {\partial f(g(z),z) \over \partial w}} {\partial f(g(z),z) \over \partial z}$.

Note that $z \mapsto - {1 \over {\partial f(g(z),z) \over \partial w}} {\partial f(g(z),z) \over \partial z}$ is $C^1$ and so $g$ is at least $C^2$, and so $z \mapsto - {1 \over {\partial f(g(z),z) \over \partial w}} {\partial f(g(z),z) \over \partial z}$ is $C^2$.
Now repeat...

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now I understand this ;) But what about this Taylor polynomial..?

Comment: Well, you can compute the first derivative in terms of $z$ and $g(z)$ using the formula above. Then differentiate again. Messy, but doable. Or start with the formula $f(w,z) = 0$ and differentiate twice (you will still need to compute the derivative of $g$).